# generate simple sine wave in matlab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

How do I generate a simple sine wave in matlab?

I would like to generate a wave which represents a temperature signal with an amplitude of 15 degrees during a 24 hour period, how can I do this?

```
t = 1:24
x = 15.*sin(pi*t)
plot(t,x)
```

where 15 is the amplitude. This does not generate a sine wave as I expected. I was expecting to see one wave which extends over a 24 hour period with an amplitude of 15, say with the lowest value of 5 and a maximum of 20 (how do I include these in the equation?).

Comment: Add a constant and ajust frequency: `x = 5 + 15*sin(2*pi*t/24);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a constant and adjust frequency:

```
x = 5 + 15*sin(2*pi*t/24);
```

In your code the frequency is incorrect, and the sampling period is too large for that frequency: you have aliasing. That's why you don't see a sine wave.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have to with Matlab really.
If you'd like to generate a wave with fixed period of, say, `T = 24hours` you'll have to calculate the sine-function accordingly.

E.g.

```
t = 1:24;
y = 15 * sin(2*pi*t / T);
```