# Creating Sine Waves Within MatLab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, trigonometry

I'm trying to create a sine wave audio signal within MatLab based on this function:

[image: Sinusoidal Functions]

So far I have created a vector `x` that starts at `0`, increments in `0.1` to `10`

Followed by this:

`y = 3*sin(x(2*pi/4))+2;`

I have multiplied `x` by `2*pi/4` in order to resize the period to a quarter of its size, but I have errors regarding indexes being positive.

Also, is it at all possible to actually create a signal at a specific Hz.  For example if I wanted a sine wave at 800Hz?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: For a specific Hz. look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [generate simple sine wave in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959607/generate-simple-sine-wave-in-matlab)

Comment: Thanks, my next step is to investigate the `fft` after I master the basics first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code create a signal at a specific Hz and play it.

```
%duration [s]
T=1;
%sample rate [Hz] Supported by SoundCard (16000,48000,96000,192000)
Fs = 48000;
%samples
N = T*Fs;
%samples vector
t = 0 : 1/Fs : T;
%Frequency [Hz]
Fn = 800;
%Signal
y = sin(Fn*2*pi*t);
plot(t,y);
%Play sound
sound(y,Fs);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not multiplying correctly. Note the subtle difference

```
y = 3*sin(x(2*pi/4))+2;
```

and what you appear to want (note the missing multiplication)

```
y = 3*sin(x*(2*pi/4))+2;
           ^
           ^
```